# Azure App Service using Windows Containers fails to start

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I've created a Azure App Service using a custom Docker Image for Windows Containers. The image runs completely fine on my Windows machine using Docker Desktop.
However, the Azure container keeps restarting and failing.

Azure Deployment Log from Kudo:

```
05/04/2022 18:04:28.774 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - [6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28] - Attempting to start container
05/04/2022 18:04:46.474 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - [6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28] - Start container succeeded.
05/04/2022 18:04:52.593 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - [6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28] - Attempting to stop container: 6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28. Site app-myappdockertest1
05/04/2022 18:04:52.593 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - [6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28] - Shutdown container: 6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28
05/04/2022 18:04:52.611 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - [6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28] - Attempting to remove container: 6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28
05/04/2022 18:04:52.992 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - Purging pending logs after stopping container
05/04/2022 18:04:52.992 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - [6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28] - Container removed successfully. Container Id: 6a0179c8984360af8ceecd4730b66112335c73c54aa0ead74a2651f9f0abcc28
05/04/2022 18:04:53.003 INFO - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - Purging after container failed to start
05/04/2022 18:04:53.003 ERROR - Site: app-myappdockertest1 - Unable to start container. Error message: One or more errors occurred.
```

I was unable to find any additional information to this error. Any idea to find detailed information about the error?

The image is based on the latest version of `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf`. It contains a .NET WCF service hosted in IIS

---

**Solution for the issue after reviewing the information given by AjayKumar-MSFT:**

The main issue was that I was using a not supported parent image. The image "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf" in its current version was based on "Windows Server Core 2022" while [Microsofts supported images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-windows#supported-parent-images) requires "Windows Server Core 2019" as of April 2022.

I've changed my Dockerfile to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
```

and was able to solve the issue. The container starts without any error message.

However AjayKumar-MSFT's tips regarding memory usage were also helpful as I was getting OutOfMemoryExceptions after the application start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as supported parent images, review the [supported list](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-windows#supported-parent-images).

--You may always, fetch more details on the errors, review the logs:
Navigate to https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole  and click the LogFiles folder to see the individual log files.

--Navigate directly to https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker  to see metadata for the Docker logs.

--You may test with the listed parent image in the doc.

Additionally,
By default, if your container does not respond after 230 seconds, it will time out. (This time out can be increased by with the WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT app setting.) and be increased to `1800`

Comment: Thank you so much! Couldn't find all this information by myself. I will work through them and give you feedback!

Comment: Thanks again! The issue was indeed that I was using a not supported parent image, because it was based on Windows Server Core 2022 instead of 2019. I edited my initial post and provided additional information that solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to know that the issue is resolved. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

Used the following base image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019` which seems to have solved the error for me.